# How to create hierarchy in puppet

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

Sorry for the trouble but I understood the use-case wrong the new use-case is as follows:

```
            common
        /            \
      Program       Data
     /    |         |      \
   Java Python    MySQL   DB
   / |     \       /     / |
   A B     C       D     E F
```

Imagine all these are manifest files including common, program .....E, F

Now if I have a server which caters to A,Java progam,then we run the A manifest, however if it is of the type 'z' Java program, then it will run the Java manifest file as the 'z' mainfest file of type Java doesn't exist.

Therefore it will look for the most specific file and make it's way up the heirachy until it finds something that it can run. If nothing matches, it runs the common manifest file.

I was thinking of using if, else if and else statements withing one manifest file for all the instructions.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: What is your actual use case? This sounds overly complicated.

Comment: Short answer is, construct a `case` construct or `if-else` chain and include whatever class(es) suit the connecting agent.

Comment: In the if else /case loop how to check whether a certain file is present and if it is present, how do we call it?

Comment: Have you looked at the concept of node classifier, or the idea of a "truth enforcer" module using Hiera as a backend for the data?